# How to add conditions to xsl for-each statements

Tags: html, xslt

I'm trying to filter out any amount below $1,000,000. Here is the code:

```
<xsl:for-each select="row">
   <tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="cell">
         <xsl:if test="position()=5">
            <td width="140" style="vertical-align: top; padding: 3px;" valign="top">
                 <xsl:choose>
                  <xsl:when test="@href">
                     <a href="">
                        <xsl:attribute name="href">
                           <xsl:value-of select="@href" />
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:value-of select="." />
                     </a>
                  </xsl:when>
                  <xsl:otherwise>
                     <xsl:value-of select="." />
                  </xsl:otherwise>
               </xsl:choose>
            </td>
         </xsl:if>
         <xsl:if test="position()=8">
            <td class="categorydetail-last-column" style="text-align: right; vertical-align: top; padding: 3px;" align="right" valign="top">
               <xsl:value-of select="." /><!-- THIS OUTPUTS NUMBERS. WANT TO FILTER NUMBERS BELOW 1000000 -->
            </td>
         </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
   </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

It outputs dollar amount but it needs to output if it's bigger than one million. I tried creating variables and wrapping the whole code in IF statement but it didn't work. What am I doing wrong? Do I have to add condition to the ROW?

Comment: "*it didn't work*" is not a good description of a problem. Post enough code to enable us **reproduce** the problem, including the input and the expected output - see" [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood, you want to process only rows in which cell No 8
contains value less than a million.

So use a template with the `match` condition specifying just this
filtering criterion:

```
<xsl:template match="row[cell[8] &lt; 1000000]">
  ...
</xsl:template>
```

If your XSLT script contains also an *identity template*, you must
somehow "block" other rows from proessing. You can do it with a
"more general", **empty** template, for **all** rows:

```
<xsl:template match="row"/>
```

Actually, it would be applied to all "other" rows (to which the former
template does not apply).

**Another solution** (more close to the script you posted):

Change the "external" loop to:

```
<xsl:for-each select="row[cell[8] &lt; 1000000]">
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Turns out, I had to add the condition OUTSIDE the row.